# Correcting Syntax Highlight files for Notepad++

Tags: windows, notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I was trying to add a syntax highlight file to Notepad++ containing syntax highlights for AutoHotkey, I followed what was in this here https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=50

but of course when I've imported it and set the defined language thing, it gives me wrong colors all over the text making white background around the text like this

[image]
How can I correct this so it's giving me the proper syntax highlights without white background on the text? it looks horrible just looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

[Right click the background color in the Styler Dialogs](https://superuser.com/questions/695921/notepad-user-defined-background-colour/939099#939099):

[image: Right click the background color in the Styler Dialog]

The transparency mark won't be remembered, but the style will.